# Can someone assist me with aligning checkbox divs on a form?

Tags: css, checkbox, haml

I have a form that I am trying to look like this on my website.

[image]

So far I've been able to render the image almost exactly. When the checkbox item is a certain length everything goes great. However, I realized that when I change the name of the checkbox item to something shorter or longer, I discovered that my form becomes a terrible mess. This is what the image looks like right now.

[image]

As you can see the checkboxes are all screwy and don't align at all.

The HAML and CSS files that I have looks like this.

```
       %div
        .stack-title
          = stack.title
        .stack-checkbox
          = check_box_tag 'stacked', 0, false, 'data-stack' => stack.to_param,
                                               'data-project' => @project.to_param,
                                               'data-stackentry' => find_stack_entry(stack, @project).to_param,
                                                target: counter
        .stack-message.message-position{ id: "message#{counter}" }
        = image_tag('spinner.gif', class: 'hidden', id: 'related_spinner', target: counter)

.stack-title
  width: 180px
  display: inline-block

.stack-checkbox
  display: inline-block
  width: 100px
  text-align: right


.stack-message
   display: inline-block
```

I was hoping if someone could point me to a JS Fiddle somewhere that can help me accomplish what I'm trying to achieve. This HTML/CSS isn't the only configuration I've tried but I've tried so many that I can't possibly post it all on this question but basically I've been trying to mess around with margin, text-align, vertical-align, and float. So far no luck. Could someone please help me......I've been working on this for far too long :/.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div around the check boxes and the text. float text left and float check box right